# Não estou conseguindo atribuir valor ao meu atributo pelo meu método

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

```
class Aluno:
    nome = ""
    ra = int
    nota_ac = []
    nota_prova = float
    faltas = int
    media = float
    aprovado = bool

    def __init__(self, arquivo):
        self.arquivo = open(arquivo, 'r')
        linha = self.arquivo.read()
        palavra = linha.split("\n")
        self.nome = palavra[0]
        self.ra = palavra[1]
        for x in palavra[2:6+1:1]:
            self.nota_ac.append(float(x))
        self.nota_prova = float(palavra[7])
        self.faltas = int(palavra[8])
        self.media = 0.0
        self.aprovado = False
        self.arquivo.close

    def calcular_aprovacao(self):
        self.media = ((sum(self.nota_ac)/5) + (self.nota_prova))/2
        if self.media >= 6.0 and int(self.faltas) <= 20:
            self.aprovado = True
            return self.aprovado
        else:
            self.aprovado = False
            return self.aprovado

    def mostrar_nota(self):
        self.media = ((sum(self.nota_ac)/5) + (self.nota_prova))/2
        return self.media

    def escrever_situacao(self, nome_arquivo):
        arq = open(nome_arquivo, 'w')
        freq = ((80 - self.faltas)/80)*100
        arq.write(self.ra+':'+self.nome+"\n")
        arq.write(str("%.2f" % Aluno.mostrar_nota(self) + "\n"))
        arq.write(str("%.1f" % freq)+"%"+"\n")
        if Aluno.calcular_aprovacao(self) is True:
            arq.write("Aprovado")
        else:
            arq.write("Reprovado")
```

Bom Galera fiz esse código que simplesmente pega os valores de um arquivo .txt faz alguns calculos e cria outro arquivo txt com a media e se foi aprovado ou não. Meu único problema é que eu nao estou conseguindo atribuir a conta da media no meu atributo self.media, gostaria de saber o porque, e tambem gostaria de saber se meu código esta com mais coisa do que deveria. Faz quase 1 ano que estou estudando python.

Comment: Esclareça melhor o que pretendia que acontecesse e o que está efetivamente a acontecer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, sempre que puder tente fornecer o máximo de informações possíveis para facilitar o entendimento de quem está tentando ajudar, ok?

Visto isso, dei uma olhada no seu código e botei ele pra rodar aqui, funcionou normalmente,pelo menos pelo que eu entendi do erro. Mas continuando sobre o seu código vou fazer algumas observações:

Dentro da classe Aluno você instanciou seus atributos com referências para as classes que eles representam deixando o código um pouco poluido:

```
class Aluno:
    nome = ""
    ra = int
    nota_ac = []
    nota_prova = float
    faltas = int
    media = float
    aprovado = bool
```

Isso é um fator desnecessário em minha opinião visto que python é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica, ou seja, ela fica responsável por esse papel durante sua execução e você não precisa se preocupar, além disso, dentro do seu construtor(**init**) você criou um atributo de instância **arquivo** desnecessário e ainda realizou algumas operações, todos esses fatores complicam muito o entendimento e não contribui para que você tenha um código limpo.

A alternativa seria você individualizar a operação de abertura e análise do arquivo dentro de um método, e como esse método não vai estar ligada ao objeto Aluno e sim a classe, ele pode ser um **staticmethod**, poderia ser um **classmethod** mas como não pretendemos modificar o estado da classe, nem acessar nenhum atributo dela iremos optar pelo **staticmethod**

Exemplo:

```
class Aluno:
    def __init__(self,arquivo,aprovado=False):
        palavras = Aluno.cria_aluno(arquivo)
        self.nome = palavras[0]
        self.ra = palavras[1]
        self.notas_ac = [float(nota) for nota in palavras[2:7]]
        self.nota_prova = float(palavras[7])
        self.faltas = int(palavras[8])
        self.set_media()
        self.aprovado = aprovado

    @staticmethod
    def cria_aluno(arquivo):
        arq = open(arquivo,'r')
        palavras = arq.read().split("\n")
        arq.close()
        return palavras
```

Perceba que para definir a media eu utilizei um método que ja atribui a média dentro do próprio construtor.

```
def set_media(self):
   self.media = ((sum(self.notas_ac)/len(self.notas_ac)) + (self.nota_prova))/2
```

Sobre seu método de calcular aprovação, perceba que você ta precisando chamar o **return** duas vezes, facilitaria se você apenas chamasse ele uma vez, no final do método retornando o próprio **self.aprovado**

```
def calcular_aprovacao(self):
        if self.media>=4 and self.faltas<=20:
            self.aprovado=True
        else:
            self.aprovado=False

        return self.aprovado
```

Perceba que eu não preciso mais calcular a média toda vez que eu quiser calcular a aprovação, pois eu ja fiz isso durante a criação da instância do aluno.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Eu peço ate desculpas pelo post, não expliquei exatamente o que eu queria. Gostaria de agradecer pelo seu post, ele sanou todas as minhas duvidas em relação aos atributos que ficavam antes do __init__, a partes dos métodos também. Em relação static method, eu só usei ele algumas vezes em classes abstratas, por isso não utilizei ele anteriormente, não sabia que era tao versátil.  Agradeço desde já.